# What happens If an SQL query takes more time and the left age of CONN_MAX_AGE is less?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Using:

- Django 1.10 and MySQL

I would like to timeout a query when a particular query takes longer time. One closest thing I found is this.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#conn-max-age

`CONN_MAX_AGE`

> The lifetime of a database connection, in seconds. Use 0 to close database connections at the end of each request — Django’s historical behavior — and None for unlimited persistent connections.

Let's assume the following scenario:

- `CONN_MAX_AGE` is set to 5 seconds
- On an average, each DB query takes 3 seconds.

---

1. Request #1 comes in and since there is no active conn, It creates a connection and set the connection age to 5 seconds.
2. Request #1 finishes after 3 seconds and age left for conn to expire is 2 seconds.
3. Now, Request #2 comes in, Since the conn is available it uses the old open conn.

---

Now, What happens to Request #2? Will it finish successfully or Will it terminate because the conn this query is using has less time left to expire?

Answer (score 2):

No, `CONN_MAX_AGE` only starts after a request has completed. It is used to pool existing connections instead of constantly closing and opening new ones.

What you are looking for is MySQL's `max_execution_time` setting:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET max_execution_time=5000'
        }
    }
}
```

This will limit each statement to a maximum of 5 seconds.